# Как вытянуть с DLE $tpl->set

Tags: php

Вот нужно вытянуть эту функцию к себе на php хост. Сохранил на хосте файл с DLE, где находится функция set.

PHP код:

```
include ("./templates.class.php");
```

и все равно он показывает :

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in /home/makar3000/html/****/index.php on line 18`

PHP код:

```
$tpl->set( '$login', $PHP_SELF . "?do=login" );
```

Comment: Не понял ответа... Мне нужно вытянуть, а вы вообще не по теме написали =(

Comment: Вот я сам и хочу узнать. И прошу, чтобы мне помогли вытянуть эту составляющую...

Comment: @shurik говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь работать с не созданным объектом. Переменная `$tpl` - пустышка, пока она не инициализирована конструктором класса. Из-за этого ошибка. Дожно быть что-то типа:

    $tpl = new ClassName(бла-бла-бла);
    $tpl->set( '$login', $PHP_SELF . "?do=login" );

Comment: rghost.ru/13224641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по исходнику, если использовать `templates.class.php` отдельно от DLE, то должно быть что-то типа:

```
$tpl = new dle_template();
$tpl->load_template("template_name");
$tpl->set( '$login', $PHP_SELF . "?do=login" );
```

Comment: Ну смотрите, я указываю `$tpl->load_template("путь к шаблону main.tpl");` и шаблон не грузится + `$tpl->set( '$login', $PHP_SELF . "?do=login" );` не работает.

Comment: Судя по исходнику метода `load_template()`, файлы шаблона должны лежать в той же папке, что и `templates.class.php`. А в качестве `$tpl_name` нужно указывать имя файла без пути к нему.

Comment: Сделал но.... Мне нужно сделать переадресацию вот допустим есть:
$tpl->sub_load_template('login.tpl') мне нужно что бы он открывался вот index.php?do=login.  А вот у меня не получается так =(

+ 

> if($PHP_SELF['login']) {  include
> ("./templates/login.tpl");  };

не пойдет! т.к мне нужно использовать много шаблонов


Answer (score 0):

Ответ очевиден, $tpl не объект.
Сделайте var_dump($tpl); и убедитесь в этом сами.

Comment: нет тоже не работает